# Laravel view composers being executed twice

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, view, laravel-blade

I have xdebug running on the server and the laravel debug bar and can see each of my view composers are being executed twice. I have placed them inside filters.php which is definitely only being ran once. What might I be doing wrong?

Alex

*edit*

view composers are being included like so:

```
View::composer('dir.view', function ($view) {
    $view->with('variable', 'value');
});
```

templates are called like so:

```
return View::make('dir.view', array());
```

and the templates look like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<p>content</p>

@stop
```

*edit 2*

somebody here seems to have experienced a similar problem http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=38657

Comment: Where is any piece of code?

Comment: Have added some but I don't think it will help

Comment: Try changing your `dir.view` template into just `<p>content</p>` and look if it also will be run twice

Comment: still runs twice when not including or extending anything

Comment: somebody here seems to have experienced a similar problem http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=38657

Answer (score 0):

It's because I used the code from this http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/auto-minify-your-html-pages article to minify the HTML, the function

```
$response->setContent($output);
```

runs all composers again.

Now need to find a way to stop it running them again.